# apt - dpkg python-rpi.gpio dependency problems

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, apt, dpkg

Every time i try to install something, upgrade or autoremove this error happens!

I've searched the web and tried some fixes but they don't seem to work, I don't have python2.7 installed only 3 and can't install python2 or anything because of this. I've tryed to sudo rm python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb but the file will keep comming. Pls I really need some help since I've got some work on my pi and don't want to get a new image

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-rpi.gpio
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-rpi.gpio
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 152893 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-rpi.gpio.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-rpi.gpio.prerm: pyclean: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: warning: old python-rpi.gpio package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 new python-rpi.gpio package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-rpi.gpio.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-rpi.gpio.postinst: pycompile: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-rpi.gpio package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Some notes: I really really don't want to change the SD Card and parcially lose what I have, second I've tried sudo `apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt update --fix-missing` when i followed this [guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/) the `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq` command was showing this error `dpkg: error: unknown force/refuse option 'remove'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I still had remainnings of Python2 and Python3 binaries and those were not linked properly by the OS, this means that Python3 was linked to Python2 and vice-versa.
To get it working I had to:

- Uninstall the Python2 dependencies
- Get the link working correctly
- Reinstall Python2 with `wget`
- Verify if all links are working correctly (for Raspbian this means):

  - python --version links to Python2
  - python2 --version links to Python2
  - python3 --version links to Python3

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives//python-rpi.gpio_0.7.0-0.1~bpo10+4_armhf.deb
```

Still have the same problem, use:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-rpi.gpio.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python-rpi.gpio
```

A typo in your command `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq` isn't valide. The correct option is `--force-remove-reinstreq`. See `dpkg --force-help`.